# Set timeout to unresponded hosts in ARP request with libpcap

Tags: c, network-programming, libpcap

I made a simple arp request program in C. I generate a host list based on my IP and subnet mask and send arp request for each ip. In the end I gather the results and print the responded computers MAC addresses to screen.

### Preface

I use `libpcap`  implementation in C to handle the process of sending and receiving packets.

First I create a handler.

```
pcap_t pcapHandler;
if (!(pcapHandler = pcap_create(interfaceName, errorBuffer))) {
    error(errorBuffer, EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if ((pcap_set_snaplen(pcapHandler, 64)) < 0) {
    error(pcap_geterr(pcapHandler), EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if ((pcap_set_promisc(pcapHandler, 1)) < 0) {
    error(pcap_geterr(pcapHandler), EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if ((pcap_set_timeout(pcapHandler, 0)) < 0) {
    error(pcap_geterr(pcapHandler), EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if ((pcap_activate(pcapHandler)) < 0) {
    error(pcap_geterr(pcapHandler), EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

and then I attach a filter to receive only arp responses to my computer

```
  struct bpf_program filter;
  char *filter_string;
  filter_string = makeMessage("ether dst %.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x and "
                              "(arp or (ether[14:4]=0xaaaa0300 and "
                              "ether[20:2]=0x0806) or (ether[12:2]=0x8100 "
                              "and ether[16:2]=0x0806) or "
                              "(ether[12:2]=0x8100 and "
                              "ether[18:4]=0xaaaa0300 and "
                              "ether[24:2]=0x0806))",
                              interface_mac[0], interface_mac[1],
                              interface_mac[2], interface_mac[3],
                              interface_mac[4], interface_mac[5]);

  if ((pcap_compile(pcapHandler, &filter, filter_string, 1, subnet_mask)) < 0) {
    error(pcap_geterr(pcapHandler), EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if ((pcap_setfilter(pcapHandler, &filter)) < 0) {
    error(pcap_geterr(pcapHandler), EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

In the end I use a user defined function to prepare the arp request. I simply call

```
 sent = pcap_sendpacket(pcapHandler, ARPBuffer, ARPBufferLength);

  if (sent < 0) {
    error(pcap_geterr(pcapHandler), EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

afterwards to send the packet.

My problem is in the stage of receiving the arp response (if any).

I use a for loop to iterate each host address and send it a arp packet.

```
HE *currHost; // list of my current host informations.
  for (currHost = hostListHead; currHost != NULL; currHost = currHost->next) {
    printf("Testing: %s\n", inet_ntoa(currHost->addr));

    // function that take the handler the current host details and my wireless interface I use to generate and send arp packages
    sendARPRequest(pcapHandler, currHost, workingWI);

    // dispatcher
    pcap_dispatch(pcapHandler, -1, callback, NULL);
  }
```

Then in the callback function I get the response and proceed it.

### Problem

My loop stacks on each host. Let's say I send an arp request in some address that doesn't contain any computer. My program don't proceed to next host but waits to get a response. The program continue with another host only when I get a response from my router (why is this possible?)

Is there any way to set a timeout? So when I don't get any response for let's say `20 ms` to proceed to next one? But I don't know even if I can proceed the packet when a client respond. Is something wrong with my implementation?

### UPDATE

After Gil's proposed this is the new code I use, and again I have the same issues:

```
pcap_t *pcapHandler;

void alarm_handler() {
  pcap_breakloop(pcapHandler);
}

void startLocalMode(WI **workingWI) {
  HE *hostListHead;
  int numberOfHosts = generateHostList(&hostListHead, (*workingWI)->address, (*workingWI)->subnet_mask);

  
  preparePCAPHandler(&pcapHandler, (*workingWI)->name);
  setPCAPHandlerFilter(&pcapHandler, (*workingWI)->interface_mac, (*workingWI)->subnet_mask);


  HE *currHost;
  int i = 0;
  for (currHost = hostListHead; i < numberOfHosts; currHost = currHost->next) {
    sendARPRequest(pcapHandler, currHost, (*workingWI));
    ++i;
  }
  alarm(2);
  signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
  pcap_loop(pcapHandler, 0, handleARPresponce, (u_char*)hostListHead);
}
```

This is the callback function:

```
#define ETHER_HDR_SIZE 14   /* Size of Ethernet frame header in bytes */
#define ARP_PKT_SIZE 28 /* Size of ARP Packet in bytes */

void handleARPresponce(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet_in) {
  int n = header->caplen;
  if (n < ETHER_HDR_SIZE + ARP_PKT_SIZE) {
    //printw("%d byte packet too short to decode\n", n);
    return;
  }

  arp_ether_ipv4 arpei;
  ether_hdr frame_hdr;
  struct in_addr source_ip;
  HE *temp_cursor;
  unsigned char extra_data[MAX_FRAME];
  size_t extra_data_len;
  int vlan_id;
  int framing;

  framing = unpackageARP(packet_in, n, &frame_hdr, &arpei, extra_data, &extra_data_len, &vlan_id);
  source_ip.s_addr = arpei.spa;

  temp_cursor = findHost((HE *)args, &source_ip);
  if (temp_cursor) {
    displayARPresponce(temp_cursor, &arpei, &frame_hdr);
  }
  return;
}
```

The callback function handles responses properlyc (as I said I get requests sent to my computer from my router). Now what's the deal with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current implementation blocks forever because you're invoking `pcap_dispatch` with a `cnt` argument of `-1` which essentially says loop until a "buffer full" of packets is received. I believe that will wait until at least one packet is received, so if you get no ARP response, it will wait forever.

You are already using `pcap_set_timeout`. You are currently setting the timeout to 0. My suspicion is that a value of 0 makes it an infinite wait. (The `pcap(3)` man page says to avoid a timeout value of 0. There are other caveats there about use of the timeout as well.)

If you wish to wait 20ms, then, you should provide a value of 20 as the second argument to `pcap_set_timeout`. You will probably then want to "manually" receive the next packet with `pcap_next_ex` (rather than `pcap_dispatch` which invokes a loop inside the pcap library). The return value from `pcap_next_ex` allows you to distinguish whether a packet was actually read or the timeout expired.

All that being said, I find the architecture brittle. I would restructure the code as follows:

1. Make a list of all the hosts to which you wish to send an ARP. (You're already doing this so nothing additional really.)
2. Send an ARP request to each host in the list.
3. Set an external timeout (with `alarm(2)` say).
4. Invoke `pcap_loop` to process incoming packets.
5. For each ARP response received (in the `callback` function), find the appropriate host by scanning the list, and record the MAC address you got from the response.
6. When the timeout expires, call `pcap_breakloop` (from the signal handler, say) to exit `pcap_loop`. (You might still need to call `pcap_set_timeout` in order to ensure that `pcap_breakloop` takes effect -- see the `pcap_breakloop(3)` manual page for discussion).

In effect, you're processing all of the hosts in parallel this way. At the end of this, you have a list of hosts, each with an associated MAC address *if* the ARP succeeded.

In fact, if this is to be robust, I would go one step further and run this for multiple iterations if necessary -- that is, re-send ARP requests to machines from which you didn't get a response -- in case a request or response is dropped somewhere in your network.

Psuedo-code:

```
alarm_handler()
{
  pcap_breakloop(pcap_handler)
}

callback(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *hdr, const u_char *data)
{
  for (host in host_list) {
    if (host->IP == IP_from_ARP_packet(data)) {
      host->MAC = MAC_from_ARP_packet(data);
      host->MAC_is_known = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}

run_sweep(host_list)
{
  for (host in host_list) {
    if (!host->MAC_is_known)
      sendARPRequest(pcapHandler, host...);
  }
  alarm(SWEEP_TIMEOUT);
  signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
  pcap_loop(pcapHandler, 0, callback, NULL);
}

/* Main code */
for (host in host_list)
  host->MAC_is_known = false;

sweeps = 0;
while (sweeps++ < MAX_SWEEPS && !all_hosts_MAC_known(host_list))
  run_sweep(host_list);
```

Comment: For the second step do I use a for loop and call `sendARPRequest` inside the loop? Where do you suggest me to add `alarm` function ? After the for loop? The same question for the others steps. If you'd like to make a code sample I would appreciate it. Even a pseudocode one will be great help. `multiple iterations` this will be my next step. You suggest me to add all the code inside a loop to get that? Thank you Gil for your response.

Comment: Hi Gil. I have registered `pcap_handler` as local variable so I can't use alarm callback as I can't send user spessified arguments to it. Can I use `sleep` after the loop or is there any better alternative?

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot put it into a global variable? (Global to the module -- it does not need to be global to your entire program.) As an alternative, you could easily replace `pcap_loop` with your own custom loop. You could, for example, use `pcap_get_selectable_fd` to obtain the file descriptor used by the pcap library, then use `select(2)` to wait on either the descriptor to become readable (in which case you would call `pcap_next_ex` or `pcap_dispatch` to obtain the received packet) or until the timeout expires.

Comment: your implementation doesn't work. I really can't understand why. As you saw from my last post I had an though that might the arp package is not well structed. I post my current code. If you would like to take a look in it.

Comment: Do you get any packets back in response? Does wireshark show any being returned? Are they getting past your packet filter?

Comment: I haven't even though to analyze the packets with wireshark. Thank you very much. That was a great lesson! Now to our job. Here is the screenshot of the wireshark http://storage1.static.itmages.com/i/17/0101/h_1483279701_3191536_88a92141a1.png. I see that the packets are sent. The 42 bytes length is something that even now I can't understand if it's correct. You said that the hardware adds the padding automatically. But something that looks bad is the sender Ip address. Do you believe this is the problem? I have to check my code again.